# Multi-Timeframe request.security() function issue - Moving Average Slope/RSI Strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, moving-average

I have an issue that's arising from my script process. It utilises code that determines a sloped Moving Average from the 336 day EMA.

```
ft = input.float(2,title="Filter Top",step=0.1)
fb = input.float(-2,title="Filter Top",step=0.1)
fthigh = input.float(4, title="Filter High Top", step=0.1)
ftlow = input.float(-4, title="Filter Low Top", step=0.1)
src1=input(ohlc4,title="source")
angle(_src1) =>
    rad2degree=180/3.14159265359  //pi 
    ang=rad2degree*math.atan((_src1[0] - _src1[1])/ta.atr(27)) 

ma=ta.ema(src1,input.int(336))
ma_slope=angle(ma)

filter = ma_slope > ft and ma_slope < fthigh ? color.aqua : ma_slope < fb and ma_slope > ftlow ? color.yellow : ma_slope > fthigh ? color.orange : ma_slope < ftlow ? color.green : color.white
```

The code above simply plots a line on an alternate pane to price window and changes colors depending on the number. (e.g. a slope of 8 indicates price has been bullish for some time, while a slope of -8 indicates price has been bearish for some time and potentially allows me to spot a reversal).

Moving Average Slope

[image]

I then found an RSI/Bollinger Band Multi-Timeframe indicator that I wanted to Frankenstein into my strategy however here comes the issue. The entry condition that I want from the RSI/Bollinger indicator is on the 15 minute timeframe, and my strategy runs on the 5 minute time frame.

On top of this, for the script to function as I would like it, I am calling the source for the RSI section of code from ma_slope which is my 'id variable' for the Moving Average Slope code.

It looks something like this:

RSI/BB MTF Indicator

[image]

```
ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)


rsiLengthInput = input.int(100, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = ma_slope
maTypeInput = input.string("Bollinger Bands", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(200, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"
bbLow = rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput
bbHigh = rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput
```

The code above is the raw code transcribed from the RSI/BB Multi TF indicator and I've tried various forms of request.security() in ways such as:

```
fetchDataOn15MinuteTF(resolution, expression) =>
    request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, expression)
```

and then following with:

```
ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

// Define a function that fetches the 15-minute timeframe data
fetchDataOn15MinuteTF(resolution, expression) =>
    request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, expression)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(100, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = ma_slope
maTypeInput = input.string("Bollinger Bands", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(200, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

rsiSourceInput15 = fetchDataOn15MinuteTF("15", rsiSourceInput)

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput15), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput15), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

rsi15 = fetchDataOn15MinuteTF("15", rsi)

rsiMA = ma(rsi15, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)

bbLow = rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi15, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput
bbHigh = rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi15, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput
```

Or something to that effect, alternating variables every which way but with no luck to change the outcome (invalid entries based on buy_condition2).

My entry is then predicated on the following:

```
buy_condition2 = (filter == color.yellow) and rsi < bbLow

if buy_condition2
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=10)
```

So that when the filter in my ma_slope calculation is less than -2 (filter == color.yellow, crude) and RSI goes below the Bollinger Band, it allows for a long condition.

The result in any attempt at requesting higher timeframe data for the RSI/Bollinger Band information coupled with RSI's source being ma_slope is that long positions do not enter when conditions are correct or they enter when positions are incorrect too.

Entry Conditions not being met

[image]

Posted in main thread.

**EDIT**

1.0 I feel I should mention that there is some leeway in entry signals with ma_slope where a buy entry is valid if ma_slope value is between -1.9 and -2.1 so that is not the issue. The Moving Average Slope code is reliable for me in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

Define your time period that you wish to fetch your data from.

```
fetchDataOnHigherTF(resolution, expression) => 
    request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, expression)
```

Your resolution is the timeframe in minutes (e.g. "15" for 15m, "60" for one hour. Your expression is the pre-defined variable in your code. For me, this was "filter".

The code then reads as follows.

```
fetch15MinFilter = fetchDataOnHigherTF("15", filter)
fetch1HrFilter = fetchDataOnHigherTF("60", filter)
```

My buy condition is then updated as follows.

```
buy_condition3 = (prev_color2 == color.yellow) and (filter == color.white) and (fetch15MinFilter == color.yellow)
```

With the code applied on the 5 minute timeframe, the request.security() function then accesses the 15 minute timeframe data for my "filter" variable and requires that when the 5 minute data is valid, the 15min data must also be valid too for a buy condition to be set.